# Smook Java to Xml Parser Removing package name

Tags: java, xml, smooks

How do I remove the package name from the XML output of the Java to XML Smook parser?

Sample Code:

```
Smooks smooks = new Smooks();
ExecutionContext executionContext = smooks.createExecutionContext();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
smooks.filterSource(executionContext,
    new JavaSource(inputJavaObject),
    new StreamResult(writer));
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson We tried to parse the Java Object to XML .Then it parsing done correctly.But i am getting java object with package name.How to resolve this could u please help me..

Comment: Run the XML through an XSLT that removes the package names, alternately, use JAXB.  There are lots of ways to clean the data of package names.

Comment: Are you new to Google?  I would throw 'xslt+tutorial' into it & go from there.  As it is, I am voting to close as 'not a real question'.